# My application does not run on client machine

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I have created application in visual studio 2015 .

1: I used service based database in visual studio because there is no option for local database .

2: On my own computer it run good .

3: On client machine it does not run .

4: I have installed sql server 2008 and sql managment studio also on client machine but it does not run .

5: Is there any way to change this application that no need for server installation in client machine .

6: I am very worry about it because I have completed the whole project .

7: It showed the following error :

In this image showed the error but my connection string is also correct and I also install the server:

[image]

Comment: Show your connection string, did you verify (through SQL Management Studio) that LocalDB exists?

Comment: con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = " + filepathofdatabase + "; Integrated Security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets =True;");

Comment: Given that LocalDB is specifically intended for developers, it probably shouldn't exist on a client machine. If you have installed SQL Server 2008 on the client then you need to specify the instance that you installed on that machine rather than an instance that existed on your development machine. The connection string is stored in the config file so you can edit it there.

Comment: what is the instance of SQL Server 2008

Comment: Instance name is depending on what you named it during your install for SQL. Also not sure why you would install SQL on client machine, it should be hosted somewhere else.

Comment: if it hosted somewhere else then how i can find the instance name of it

Comment: Is there any way to change this to SQLCE

Answer (score -1):

disable firewall from your computer then check it.

Comment: Hi user9412478, to get a good answer you need to create a good question. Try being a bit more specific. You asked about disabling a firewall, but you did not mention the operating system on the computer or the firewall software you want disabling.  Then what do you want to check it for, that it has been disabled?  Try editing your question and adding in these details. Also this question would be better suited to be asked here instead: https://superuser.com

Comment: does for local database(server based database)need localdb.msi on client machine or to install a server on client machine for it